# How do I split the data in the column while loading in neo4j using neo4j-admin import?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import 2 csv files where 1 has nodes and another has relationship. In relationship, I have a column where data needs to be splitted. I tried using --array-delimiter='|' but I get an error. I was hoping if someone could help me with this issue.

```
node.csv

identifier:ID,name:LABEL
1,apple
2,ball
3,cat

rel.csv

source_ids:START_ID,target_ids:END_ID,type:TYPE,data
1,2,connection,
2,3,relation,test1|test2
3,1,connection,test1
1,3,relation,test4|test3|tet6
```

If I use the command below, I get data with | in it. It will not split data field.

```
neo4j-admin import --verbose --ignore-extra-columns=true  --nodes C:/Users/Sam/Documents/node.csv --relationships C:/Users/Sam/Documents/rel.csv.
```

I get result in a format of :

```
{
  "data": "test4|test3|tet6"
}
```

What I want is :

```
{
  "data": ["test4","test3","tet6"]
}
```

When I try:

```
neo4j-admin import --verbose --ignore-extra-columns=true --array-delimiter= "|"  --nodes C:/Users/Sam/Documents/node.csv --relationships C:/Users/Sam/Documents/rel.csv.
```

I get an error:

```
Invalid value for option '--array-delimiter': cannot convert '' to char (java.lang.Ill
egalArgumentException: Unsupported character '')
[picocli WARN] Could not format 'Maximum memory that neo4j-admin can use for various d
ata structures and caching to improve performance. Values can be plain numbers, like 1
0000000 or e.g. 20G for 20 gigabyte, or even e.g. 70%.' (Underlying error: Conversion
= '.'). Using raw String: '%n' format strings have not been replaced with newlines. Pl
ease ensure to escape '%' characters with another '%'.
[picocli WARN] Could not format 'Maximum memory that neo4j-admin can use for various d
ata structures and caching to improve performance. Values can be plain numbers, like 1
0000000 or e.g. 20G for 20 gigabyte, or even e.g. 70%.' (Underlying error: Conversion
= '.'). Using raw String: '%n' format strings have not been replaced with newlines. Pl
ease ensure to escape '%' characters with another '%'.
[picocli WARN] Could not format 'Maximum memory that neo4j-admin can use for various d
ata structures and caching to improve performance. Values can be plain numbers, like 1
0000000 or e.g. 20G for 20 gigabyte, or even e.g. 70%.' (Underlying error: Conversion
= '.'). Using raw String: '%n' format strings have not been replaced with newlines. Pl
ease ensure to escape '%' characters with another '%'.
```

Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define an array type, append [] to the type. Example:

```
source_ids:START_ID,target_ids:END_ID,type:TYPE,data:[]
```

[Refer documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/file-header-format/)

Comment: Thank you. I need to add type and []. For other people who might come across this issue. I had to change the header to source_ids:START_ID,target_ids:END_ID,type:TYPE,data:STRING[]

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous space character in your command line.

Change:

```
--array-delimiter= "|"
```

to:

```
--array-delimiter="|"
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't get an error when I remove the space but I am still not getting desired output. My data still looks like  {"data": "test4|test3|tet6"}. I want is {
  "data": ["test4","test3","tet6"]
}